# Ldap filter to search for users in a given domain (using powershell)

Tags: powershell, active-directory, lync

How would I write an LDAP filter to search for user objects in a given domain? Basically I'm trying to get all Lync users from a given domain

I've tried this:

```
get-csuser -LdapFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(dc=mytestlab,dc=com))"
```

but this gives me no results.

Basically, the domain is mytestlab.com and all I want to do is get users from this particualr domain. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the following filter should work:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(dc:dn:=mytestlab)(dc:dn:=com))
```

The filter above is called an *extensible match search* because it specifies an attribute name: dc and the DN’s attributes should be considered as part of the entry.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. I also tried it with get-aduser -LDAPFilter and used your filter, but that didn't return anything either. Also, it seems like AD has limited support for extensible filters as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223241.aspx

Comment: Ah, sorry had only tested against a local ApacheDs server - should have thought that AD would be different.